# MVC4 - Facebook (Login Failure. Unsuccessful login with service.)

Tags: .net, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth

I am testing an .NET MVC4 application using facebook OAuth services. When I use my facebook account (which I already authorized the application), I have no problem. But when I use my wife's account I am always redirected to the ExternalLoginFailure page.

The piece of code that redirects me to there is this:

AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
            if (!result.IsSuccessful)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }

result.IsSuccessful is always false but I don't know why.

I tried to use log4net to log info but no success.
I tried to update OAuth assemblies but no success.
I tried to use Glimpse but no sucess.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is the Facebook app prompting for authorization on that account, or just automatically directing to the login failure?  Is it possible that the Facebook account in question has blocked that app, or blocked all apps?

Comment: I can't get to the authorization page. After authentication I am redirected to the ExternalLoginFailure. Authenticantion is done correctly cause if I access facebook's page, I can see I am logged.

Comment: Did you resolve this.  I am having the same issue.

Comment: No jle, I didn't. I am still waiting for somebody's answer.

Comment: I just found the answer. The problem was the way my app was configured on facebook developer's page. If you forget to disable Sandbox Mode only your own user will be able to access your app. After I disabled Sandbox Mode I was able to login using another account and the "Login Failure" message was gone.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Previously I was able to do the login. Now suddenly I have changed something and it is providing the same problem. I can't identify what I have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make it publicly available. To do this:

1. Login to https://developers.facebook.com
2. Select Your App
3. Click settings and ensure a contact email is set (If you dont have this you cant complete step 4)
4. Click Status & Review
5. Toggle '
   Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?' switch

Now you are able to access the application from all accounts.